# How to install unpacked extension in firefox & chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

i have created extension by using crossrider they gave me xpi & crx file which i extracted and want to install manually by copying data to the browser's extension path.

I've read & tried many posts regarding this but they are not helpful because i think some posts are old & not able to find target paths & registry.
like in many posts they say create the following key in the registry here

```
32-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
```

but i couldn't find that on my windows registry & i am using 32bit.

i want something like i copy my extension data to the browser's extension directory & inject some registry value thats all. if it possible then How?

Answer (score 4):

For firefox just add the xpi  or unpacked folder to the profile folder. No need for registry so its cross platform.

It can't be automatic as spyware would be all over that. After placing xpi in the extensions folder of the profile, on next startup of Firefox it will prompt saying it found an unauthorized by user add-on, and gives user a chance to enable it, or keep it disabled.

If you want to do it without startup, just launch the file path to the xpi or unpacked folder (if unpacked folder doesnt work, then point it to the install.rdf) in the browser, user will be prompted if they want to install.

There are some registry options though: [Install Firefox extension using Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888316/install-firefox-extension-using-windows-registry)

Comment: `or unpacked folder to the profile folder`. Where is the profile folder?

Comment: `%appdata%\mozilla` however I've been trying to load the unpacked (only js files, manifest) to firefox and have failing... there's no simple *how-to*... I don't want to create a xpi file or else... only load the folder where the files are... chrome is soooo much easier

Comment: @JobaDiniz may you please link me to the Chrome instructions, I will try to find you something in same format.

Comment: @Notidart [temporary installation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox) "open the extension's directory and select **any** file inside the extension". That's the catch, select any file and not the folder itself

Comment: Thanks @JobaDiniz - may you please share a link the Chrome docs, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: @Notidart [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked) it is

Comment: Oh I see now @JobaDiniz - yes for firefox you have to go to `about:debugging` and then select the `manifest.json` from inside your adodon.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, [it's no longer possible to add an extension programmatically on Windows](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) unless the extension is actually published in the Store.

This is for security reasons: previous registry-based (and otherwise) methods were open to malware abuse.

If your extension is published in the store, you can [add it semi-automatically via registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry). The user will still be asked whether to enable it on the next load.

---

You can also install extensions silently [using Enterprise policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) (**only** if the machine is part of a Windows domain and you have admin rights on the domain policy), on [other OSes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#preferences), or load it unpacked for testing with the [`--load-extension` command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension) (will not persist after Chrome is restarted).

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome go to

```
chrome://extensions
```

Enable *Developer Mode* at the top and click on the button to load an extracted extension.

Comment: i know this but i want to install manually by using filesystem & registry